# How to use MLlib in spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib

Lately, I've been learning about spark sql, and I wanna know, is there any possible way to use mllib in spark sql, like :

```
select mllib_methodname(some column) from tablename;
```

here, the "mllib_methodname" method is a mllib method.
Is there some example shows  how to use mllib methods in spark sql?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Currently I don't think , SQL is mainly meant for dataware housing and pre processing the data , you can surely build the dataset using SQL and then run in MLlib , but I couldn't find the other way around

Comment: I think I can customize the function in the sql to call method in MLlib

Comment: That will be great and you may check spark buglist , if its not there you may contribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new pipeline API is based on DataFrames, which is backed by SQL. See

http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-guide.html

Or you can simply register the predict method from MLlib models as UDFs and use them in your SQL statement. See

http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#udf-registration-moved-to-sqlcontextudf-java--scala